# Update columns from duplicate table with columns that only contain data other than 0

Tags: php, pdo, duplicates

I want to write a pdo statement for updating a table under the following conditions.
I have duplicate tables Master and Updates. 
When I update a row in the Master table from the Updates table with a corresponding id, I do NOT want to replace column data in the Master table with column data in the Updates table that contain a default value of "0". In other words, if a column in the Updates table contains "0", then there was no update made to that column data, thus, the corresponding Master table column should not be updated. All other columns in the Updates table that contain data should update corresponding columns in the Master table.

I know how to write a pdo UPDATE statement but could not find any examples how to include the condition as I described above in the statement. Any pointers would be greatly appreciated.

A side note - I set up this scheme because I want to review updates before updating a record in the Master table.

Comment: If you don;t need a killer query - then select all records from `Updates` table where something is not zero and update corresponding `Master` records.

Comment: @u_mulder Not sure what you mean. Each row contains columns with data and columns with zero

Comment: For any column in the master table you do: Update master column if `updates` column is not zero or  update the master column with the current master column value. i.e. update with new value from updates or itself. This will  do what you want in one update statement.

Answer (score 0):

After giving this some thought, I guess I could populate the Update form with data from the Master table, thus, when submitted, I eliminate any default values of zero being created in the Update table.

However, I still would be interested if anyone has a good answer to my original question.